# How to pass interface to child component in react using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Ok I'm new to using Typescript for react, but I've been programming long enough that this problem makes me feel very dumb...

Literally all I want to do, is define an interface that acts as the `type` for a property that you pass to a child component.

Like so...

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

const Child = ({ foo } : Foo) => {

    console.log(foo)

    return <Text>Hello World</Text>

}

const TestPage = () => {

    const fooObject : Foo = { bar: 'something' }

    return <Child foo={fooObject} />

}
```

But I keep seeing this error underlining the `foo` property I pass in inside the `return` statement on the `TestPage` component:

```
Type '{ foo: Foo; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Foo'.
  Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Foo'.
```

And this error underlining the deconstructed `foo` property coming in on the child component:

```
Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Foo'.
```

This seems so basic to me, can someone please explain?

Comment: I will also add that this code works, but these damn underlines are annoying me so much lol

Comment: Foo doesn't have a foo

Comment: `{ foo } : Foo` is the same as `const Child = (props: Foo) => { const foo = props.foo }` which doesn't make sense because `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Foo'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Child = ({ foo } : Foo) => {
```

This means that the entire props object is a `Foo`. It does not mean that `foo` is a `Foo`. You want:

```
const Child = ({ foo }: { foo: Foo }) => {
```

Or giving it a named type:

```
interface ChildProps {
  foo: Foo
}

const Child = ({ foo }: ChildProps) => {
```

Comment: Ugh.. yes you're totally right, I should have been able to see this. Thanks for answering!